# Tooltip hover flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add tooltips (via Bootstrap) such that when you hover over an image, it shows the tooltip after a 500ms delay. The image has a regular state and a hover state:

CSS:

```
.image {
  background-image: url('../img/test.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}

.image:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.image').tooltip({title: 'Text', delay: { show: 500, hide: 0 }, trigger: 'hover', html: true});
```

The problem is that when I hover over the image to check the tooltip, the image flashes without ever showing the tooltip, as such:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/S6YvXFT.gif]

Comment: Can you show us your javascript code?

Comment: I've edited my original post with it. :)

Comment: @JohnSmith I dont see it here http://jsfiddle.net/WnAae/

Comment: Yeah, it works fine for me in JSFiddle too, but it doesn't work on my own site. :/

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine.  Are you not including jQuery, or perhaps since you forgot to assign a height and width it's popping up somewhere you don't expect?

`jsfiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/8S7kP/1/

Comment: Yeah, it works fine for me in JSFiddle too, but it doesn't work on my own site. :/

Comment: Is it publicly addressable?